# Greatest number or highest number

Tags: grammar

What is the different between `greatest` and `highest` to describe number?

**Example**

> I used below code to find greatest and smallest number

**OR**

> I used below code to find highest and smallest number

Comment: Actual numbers are highest and lowest number: 100, 200, 300 versus 1, 2, 3, for example.  Whereas: the greatest number of people would take great to mean largest. That's the short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know for a fact that in mathematics people only use terms like **greatest**, **lowest**, **smallest**, **least**, **less** and other variations thereof when talking about relationships between numerical quantities. I don't think you very often see phrases such as **highest value** or **highest number** in mathematics, but I'll be the first to admit that in casual speech such locutions are definitely possible. Also, instead of **greatest** and **smallest number**, you could often hear people say **maximum** and **minimum number**.

Here's a list of some of the most popular terms used in math with regards to your question about the difference between greatest and highest (the truth is that **highest** is rarely, if ever, used):

> the greatest common factor
>   the least common denominator
>   the greater than sign 
>   the less than sign
>   the greatest integer function
>   the least integer function
>   the maximum value of a function
>   the minimum value of a function

Comment: Also largest and biggest.